# What happens in a raid (5) when one drive or more gets a bad sector?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, nas

A very simple question that I couldn't find a clear simple answer on anywhere online!

I have a RAID 5 in a NAS box of 4 physical hard drives and two of them are now reporting a few bad sectors.   I just want to understand what happens in terms of how the drives relate to each other and if damaged data in the bad drives can get copied over easily to the others.

Is that bad block copied bad to the other drives blindly (I assume not)?  My limited understanding as to how the data is laid out over the disks in a raid 5 may explain the naivety of this question.

I use QNAP NAS boxes and so whilst this question is more focused at Linux it's a general question I would prefer not be answered just to the scenario of Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

> Is that bad block copied bad to the other drives blindly (I assume not)?

It's possible, yes.

If you were to perform a "*Verify and Repair*" type operation, then it is possible for bad data to be considered correct, and for the parity device to be updated... even when the parity device is in fact correct, and one of the other devices is at fault.

---

This is question does not have a simple answer as there are many variables at play here.

"RAID5" might sound like a standard *thing*... but it isn't. RAID5 isn't a standard between different manufacturer implementations, and potentially even between different products of a given manufacturer. The fact that this term is becoming more and more popular for simply referring to "*storage with one parity device*" muddies the waters further. Due to this alone, it's not easy to give you an "*it'll do this*" answer.

With a "*hardware RAID*" setup you'll often find that undetected read errors are passed up through the system as successful without even verifying the data against the parity device - i.e: if a sector is not detected as bad by the storage device, then parity doesn't help.

With more modern and advanced filesystems such as [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) and [Btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) the data is checksummed and verified much more carefully (data hasn't been checksummed or verified at all previously). Here, a silent read error will be detected and corrected, even though the storage device was unable to detect it. Additionally, it's possible to determine if the parity device is at fault, or if the other device is at fault.

When a storage device *knows* that a read was bad, then there are also a drastically different possibilities. Within the magnetic storage (Hard Disk Drive) arena you will find that:

- Desktop drives will typically try over and over again to perform a successful read. During this time they will often appear to be non-responsive, and this can last for seconds. This makes sense, as such a disk is intended to be used by itself, without redundancy.
- Enterprise or "*NAS*" drives will tend to declare failure more readily, preferring to remain available. Again, this makes sense, because this class of disk expects to be able to fall back on a mirror or parity device for error recovery at a higher level. (Look into [Time-Limited Error Recovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control))

When it comes to bad sectors on disks, there are two levels at which their management can be performed.

1. The disk itself may decide that a sector is "*bad*" during an I/O operation.
2. The filesystem may record a sector as "*bad*", and purposefully avoid it.

With modern disks #1 is more common, but with older disks #2 was the way - some *old* disks even came with a list of bad sectors from the factory, which you had to type in when commissioning.

Disks won't typically relocate "*bad*" sectors on a read error (so you can try again), while a failed write will result in a relocation.

To dive even deeper, there are two main failure modes for a given sector:

- The data looks wrong, but the medium appears to be working fine.

  - A read error can be caused by bit flips or reduced signal due to poor magnetic orientation.
  - A write (or re-write) will work fine, and the data will subsequently be read correctly.
- The data looks wrong, and the medium doesn't work correctly.

  - A read error can be caused by more fundamental issues with the storage medium - for example scratches from a head crash.
  - A write will not work correctly. This will usually trigger a sector to be relocated.

Answer (score 2):

Most systems treat it the same way they would a bad sector in a non-RAID device.

When a system finds a bad sector on any device, RAID or not, it attempts to read from that sector and move the data to another sector. It will do the same thing to the RAID device. The only difference is that it is much more likely that it will be able to successfully move the data to another sector of the logical RAID device since the data can be reconstructed.

Typically, the RAID layer reports to the next layer up that the logical sector is bad but that it was able to read its contents. That next layer up typically assigns a new logical sector, writes the data there, and updates its tracking information accordingly.