# solid state disk some random files corrupted; how to prevent in simple terms

Tags: ssd, raid, bad-sectors, btrfs, bad-blocks

Please see [What happens in a raid (5) when one drive or more gets a bad sector?](https://superuser.com/questions/1317753/what-happens-in-a-raid-5-when-one-drive-or-more-gets-a-bad-sector).  I have a few  .jpg files (and much more serious data).  Some of the .jpg files become corrupted.  I can tell because they are unviewable with viewer "geeqie".  I am currently using btrfs on a crucial CT512MX1 ssd bought JAN 2015.

1. (question 1) What maintenance you can do on btrfs instead of "fsck"?
2. (question 2) What are the software/hardware requirements for solid state disks in raid 1 to accomplish this?"  e.g. must it be able to read SMART data for ssd?

Here is a discussion which is too complicated:  https://linux-btrfs.vger.kernel.narkive.com/BQK0Pz9w/how-does-btrfs-handle-bad-blocks-in-raid1

Comment: First, keep backups!, second use data scrubbing. (Reading all data of the drive periodically)

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single, specific question that can be answered. Right now there's a lot of rambling, possibly several questions, and nothing very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer to Question 1 is:  use `btrfs scrub` to detect and fix damaged files:  see

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Identify_damaged_files

specifically

> "Unlike other filesystem types, btrfs has native support for reporting
> on damaged files. When scrubbing a partition, btrfs reads all data and
> metadata blocks and verifies checksums. It automatically repairs
> corrupted blocks if there is a correct copy available in a RAID
> configuration. btrfs also reports any unreadable sector along with the
> affected file via system log. "

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You said « I am currently using btrfs on a crucial CT512MX1 ssd ». A single drive can’t be considered RAID1. Then btrfs will get you many advantages, but none about redundancy. If a sector can’t be read, the file is lost (more accurately can’t be read completely). The only advantage of btrfs here is that it stores a checksum of each block and will prefer to raise an I/O error instead of sending a incorrect value for some sectors : you can’t read the file instead of your application breaks because of a corrupted file.

Comment: yes I know it is not raid1 now; I want to know if any specific hardware is required (to purchase in future) if I want to implement the raid 1 scheme as in the answer below.  or just it only necessary to get a pair of ssds for which smartd works?  For example do you need disks designed for NAS or raid or enterprise ssd instead of any desktop ssd?

Comment: Any pair of SSD can constitute a RAID 1 partition or redondant btrfs partition. NAS or enterprise drives are equal about it, but have generally a lower bit error rate (probability of error while reading). I don’t really know about SSD, but they are not all equal about the number of rewrites they support.